# Some Glyphicons displaying as empty boxes Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I'm trying to use Glyphicons with Bootstrap 3 and am finding that some of them don't work.

For example, out of these three glyphicons, the first one doesn't work (it shows up as am empty box):

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/WE6BS/

I'm using the CDN versions of the Bootstrap JS, CSS, and Glyphicons, as well as copying code directly from the Glyphicons example page, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is most likely an issue with inclusion of Glyphicons on `BootstrapCDN` 3.0.0 version. When 3.0 was released the glyphicons were in a separate repo, and then combined into the Bootstrap baseline again later around 3.0.1.

The latest 3.0.3 seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/EhwT3/

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how I got an outdated version of the CDN links, since I just started using Bootstrap this week, but that fixed the problem!